# How to solve make mysql-connector-c++-1.1.7 error

Tags: c++, mysql

After I follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-unix.html
and when I using `make`
below is what I happen

```
[  8%] Building CXX object driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_resultbind.cpp.o
/root/git/MetricBench.perclab/build/mysql-connector-cpp/driver/mysql_resultbind.cpp: In function ‘sql::mysql::st_buffer_size_type sql::mysql::allocate_buffer_for_field(const MYSQL_FIELD*)’:
/root/git/MetricBench.perclab/build/mysql-connector-cpp/driver/mysql_resultbind.cpp:89:10: error: ‘MYSQL_TYPE_JSON’ was not declared in this scope
     case MYSQL_TYPE_JSON:
          ^
driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/build.make:284: recipe for target 'driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_resultbind.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_resultbind.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:92: recipe for target 'driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have ever find out the solution others offer

```
This can be fixed by checking for the MYSQL_TYPE_JSON at compile time and optionally including those switch/case conditionals only if detected in the underlying C API.
```

and I really don't know how to solve this problem any suggestion ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql-connector-c++-1.1.6. 1.1.7 has added JSON type and it seems that it is not supported with Connector C 6.1.6 or some additional changes need to be done.

Maybe it is something else but I didn't bother too much, 1.1.6 works like a charm.

### ...found it:

---

*Changes in MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.7 (2016-01-20)*

*To build Connector/C++ from source, you must use either a General Availability version of MySQL 5.7 (5.7.9 or higher) or **Connector/C 6.1.8** or higher.*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-cpp/en/news-1-1-7.html

---

The second mistery is where to download Connector/C 6.1.8 source? Download page (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) at the time I'm writing this is offering only Connector/C 6.1.6....

### well....

after another research, it seems that Connector/C 6.1.7 and 6.1.8 are not going to be released in community versions (https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-c-relnotes-en.a4.pdf). **But**, in this document there's no mention about adding JSON type support in 6.1.8:

---

*Changes in MySQL Connector/C 6.1.8 (2015-12-15)*

Security Notes
• This release of Connector/C upgrades the linked OpenSSL library to version 1.0.1p. Issues fixed in
the new OpenSSL version are described at http://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html.

*Changes in MySQL Connector/C 6.1.7 (2015-04-21)*

*Security Notes
• Security Fix: Connector/C 6.1 Commercial has been updated to use OpenSSL version 1.0.1m,
which has been publicly reported as not vulnerable to CVE-2015-0286.
Since the only change in Connector/C 6.1.7 is the inclusion of OpenSSL libraries publicly reported
as unaffected by CVE-2015-0286, and since Oracle-produced MySQL Community builds use YaSSL
libraries which have been reported as not affected by CVE-2015-0286, **Oracle will not produce builds
for Connector/C Community for version 6.1.7. This means the Community edition of Connector/C will
skip version 6.1.7**. (Bug #20747718, CVE-2015-0286)*